# In $\triangle ABC$, if $\cos A\cos B\cos C=\frac{1}{3}$, then $\tan A\tan B+\tan B \tan C+\tan C\tan A =\text{???}$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, if 
>   $$\cos A \cos B \cos C=\frac{1}{3}$$ 
>   then can we find value of 
>   $$\tan A\tan B+\tan B \tan C+\tan C\tan A\ ?$$

Please give some hint. I am not sure if $\tan A \tan B+\tan B \tan C+\tan C \tan A$ will be constant under given condition.

Comment: Possibly use _cos(A+B) = cos(A).cos(B)  - sin(A).sin(B)_, and similar formula for _cos(π-C)_ remembering, for a triangle _A+B+C = π_ and then simplyfying.

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect, because there is no triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $\cos A \cos B \cos C=\frac 13$. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$S=\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A$$

Multiplying by $\cos A \cos B \cos C=\frac 13$, we get $$\frac 13S=\sin A\sin B\cos C+\cos A\sin B\sin C+\sin A\cos B \sin C$$

However,$$\cos(A+B+C)=-1=\cos A\cos B\cos C-\sin A\sin B\cos C-\sin A\cos B\sin C-\cos A\sin B\sin C$$

Therefore, $$\frac 13S=\cos A\cos B\cos C+1=\frac 43\Rightarrow S=4$$

Comment: Writing the formula for S as a function of cos(A)cos(B)cos(C), which follows from the same argument, would be more illuminating.

Comment: @zyx can you show us what you mean?

Comment: I meant to replace 1/3 by a variable $u$ and write S in terms of $u$.  Your method does this.  If you prefer that I edit your post to include that, I can do so.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your algebra, but I think there is no triangle for which $\cos A \cos B \cos C=\frac{1}{3}$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is no. The maximum value of $\cos A \cos B \cos C$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the angles of a triangle in the plane, is $\frac{1}{8}$, so there is no plane triangle for which $\cos A \cos B \cos C=\frac{1}{3}$.

The product $\cos A \cos B \cos C$ equals $\frac{1}{8}$ for an equilateral triangle, and the fact that this is a maximum follows from the fact that for any acute* triangle $\triangle ABC$, the product is greater for the “more equilateral” triangle with angles $\frac{A+B}{2}$, $\frac{A+B}{2}$, and $C$, because $$\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos C-\cos A\cos B\cos C= \frac{1-\cos(A+B)}{2}\cdot\cos C>0.$$

*We can assume the triangle is acute (and $\cos C>0$), because otherwise the product $\cos A \cos B \cos C \le 0$ (only one angle in a given triangle can be non-acute, so only one of the cosines can be non-positive) and $\triangle ABC$ can’t possibly be one for which $\cos A \cos B \cos C$ is a maximum.

This might be an interesting question for triangles on a surface of negative curvature, however.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a triangle ABC

$A+B=\pi-C$

and

$1-2\cos A \cos B \cos C=\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C$

Edit $1$:
$A+B=\pi-C$

Apply $\cos$ on both sides

Divide each term by $\cos A.\cos B$

We get $\tan A.\tan B=1+\frac{\cos C}{\cos A. \cos B}$

Similarly write $2$ more equations and add three equations.

Now use $1-2\cos A \cos B \cos C=\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C$

Comment: So how does that help can you tell something more

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Yes. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no triangle $\triangle ABC$ for which $\cos A\cos B\cos C=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing Mathematics's answer:

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b) and $\cos(A+B)=\cdots=-\cos C$

$\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C=1+\cos^2A-\sin^2B+\cos^2C=1-2\cos A\cos B\cos C$

If $\cos A\cos B\cos C=S$

$\iff\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C=1-2S$
let $y=\tan A\tan B\iff y-1=-\dfrac{\cos(A+B)}{\cos A\cos B}=\dfrac{\cos^2C}S$

$\iff\cos^2C=S(y-1)$

$\sum S(y-1)=\sum\cos^2C=1-2S\iff y=3+\dfrac{1-2S}S$

Here $S=\dfrac13$

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no triangle $\triangle ABC$ for which $\cos A\cos B\cos C=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @SteveKass, Observe that my answer is not dependent on the actual value of $\cos A\cos B\cos C$

Comment: @SteveKass, Simpler proof : 
If $y=\cos A\cos B\cos C,$  $$\iff2y=2\cos A\cos B\cos C=\cos A[\cos(B-C)+\cos(B+C)]$$

As $B+C=\pi-A,$  $$2y=\cos A[\cos(B-C)-\cos A]$$

$$\iff\cos^2A-\cos A\cos(B-C)+2y=0$$

As $\cos A$ is real, the discriminant $\cos^2(B-C)-8y\ge0\iff8y\le\cos^2(B-C)$

The equality occurs if $\cos^2(B-C)=1=\cos0\iff B=C$ as $0<B,C<\pi$

In that case, $$\cos^2A-\cos A+2\cdot\dfrac18=0$$  $$\iff\cos A=\dfrac12\implies A=60^\circ\implies B+C=20^\circ$$  But $B=C\implies B=C=60^\circ=A$