# Prove that $ \sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2} \le \frac{1}{8}$

Tags: trigonometry, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities, jensen-inequality

Prove that $ \sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2} \le \frac{1}{8}$ when $A,B,C$ are the angles in a triangle.

I need a help on this question, one can enter $A=B=C$ and get the maximum value $\frac{1}{8}$, but that is not a solution, but hit and trial. Can this conclusion be derived using maximum/mininum concept?

Comment: This is false as stated, e.g. if $A=B=C=\pi$. Are we missing a hypothesis?

Comment: I think $A+B+C=\pi$

Comment: A=B=C=π/3 not π/2

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi : If you had in mind that $A+B+C = \pi/3$ then you should include that in the question.

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi what do you mean by `A=B=C=π/3 not π/2` ...

Comment: I mean that for equilateral triangle A/2 =B//=C/2=30 as all angles are 60 hence substituting we get the product of half Sine Angle ad 1/8 which is maximum

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi : please read the question you asked carefully. I think you are missing some condition...

Comment: Please fix the question. It is not true as stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is the same as asking: when $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac\pi2$, what is the maximum of $\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)$?

We wish to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ so that for each $\delta\alpha,\delta\beta,\delta\gamma$ so that
$$
\delta\alpha+\delta\beta+\delta\gamma=0\tag{1}
$$
we also have
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\\
&=\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\,\delta\alpha+\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\,\delta\beta+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\,\delta\gamma\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Since each $\delta\alpha,\delta\beta,\delta\gamma$ that is perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$, it must also be perpendicular to $(\cot(\alpha),\cot(\beta),\cot(\gamma))$, we must have that $\cot(\alpha)=\cot(\beta)=\cot(\gamma)$. Thus, $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\frac\pi6$ and
$$
\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)=\frac18\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\sin x$ is concave function when $0\leq x\leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Then by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) on concave function, we have:

$$\frac{\sin \dfrac{A}{2}+\sin \dfrac{B}{2}+\sin \dfrac{C}{2}}{3}\leq \sin \dfrac{A+B+C}{2\cdot 3}=\sin\dfrac{\pi}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now by AM-GM inequality $$\frac{\sin \dfrac{A}{2}+\sin \dfrac{B}{2}+\sin \dfrac{C}{2}}{3}\geq \Big(\sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2}\Big)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$$

Hence $$\sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2} \le \frac{1}{8}$$

Equality holds when $A=B=C=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 3):

Like my answers in

[Extreme of $\cos A\cos B\cos C$ in a triangle without calculus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609327/extreme-of-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-in-a-triangle-without-calculus)

[$ \cos {A} \cos {B} \cos {C} \leq \frac{1}{8} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952893/cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-leq-frac18)

[Trigonometric Inequality $\sin{A}+\sin{B}-\cos{C}\le\frac32$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648521/trigonometric-inequality-sina-sinb-cosc-le-frac32)

[In $ \triangle ABC$ show that $ 1 \lt \cos A + \cos B + \cos C \le \frac 32$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949530/in-triangle-abc-show-that-1-lt-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-le-frac-32)

let $S=\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac C2$

$2S=\left(\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-\cos\dfrac{A+B}2\right)\sin\dfrac C2$

As $\dfrac{A+B}2=\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac C2,$

$2S=\left(\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-\sin\dfrac C2\right)\sin\dfrac C2$

$\iff\sin^2\dfrac C2-\sin\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+2S=0$

As $\sin\dfrac C2$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e., $$\cos^2\dfrac{A-B}2-8S\ge0\iff8S\le\cos^2\dfrac{A-B}2\le1$$

So, $8S\le1\implies S\le\frac{1}{8}$

the equality occurs if $\cos\dfrac{A-B}2=1\iff\cos(A-B)=1\iff A=B$ as $0<A,B<\pi$

and hence $\sin\dfrac C2=\dfrac12\implies C=\dfrac\pi3$ as $0<C<\pi$

$\implies A=B=\dfrac{A+B}2=\dfrac\pi3=C$

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the function $f(\theta)=\log\sin\theta$ on the interval $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. It is a concave function
since $f''(\theta)=-\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}<0$, hence by Jensen's inequality
$$ f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \leq 3\,f\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right) $$
holds for any $a,b,c\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. By considering $a=\frac{A}{2},b=\frac{B}{2},c=\frac{C}{2}$ and exponentiating both sides of the previous inequality turns into
$$ \sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}\leq \sin^3\left(\frac{A+B+C}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a, b, c$ be the sides of a triangle with given angles $A, B, C$.

Recall for any $3$ positive numbers $a, b, c$, it can form the sides of a non-degenerate triangle if and only if we can find $3$ positive numbers
$u,v,w$ such that
$$a = v + w,\quad b = u + w,\quad c = u + v$$

This is known as [Ravi substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution/) for a triangle.
In terms of them, we have

$$
\sin^2\frac{A}{2} 
= \frac12( 1 - \cos A) = \frac12\left(1 - \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)
= \frac{a^2 - (b-c)^2}{4bc} = \frac{vw}{bc}
$$
By a similar argument, we have
$$\sin^2\frac{B}{2}  = \frac{uw}{ac}\quad\text{ and }\quad\sin^2\frac{C}{2} = \frac{uv}{ab}$$

Multiply these 3 relations together, taking square root and apply AM $\ge$ GM to the factors in denominator, we obtain:

$$\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}
= \frac{uvw}{abc}
= \frac{uvw}{(v+w)(u+w)(u+v)}
\le \frac{uvw}{(2\sqrt{vw})(2\sqrt{uw})(2\sqrt{uv})} = \frac18$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}=\frac{r}{4R}\leq\frac{1}{8}.$$

Another way.

Since $f(x)=\ln\sin\frac{x}{2}$ is a concave function, by Jensen and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\leq\sin^2\frac{\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\beta}{2}}{2}\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}+\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{8}.$$
Done!

Comment: What are $R$ and $r$?

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor $r$ it's a radius of the inscribed circle and $R$ is a radius of the circumcircle.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: why not give that information in your answer? Is it obvious that $\frac{r}{R}\le\frac12$?