# triangle inequality with $\cos$ and triangle angles

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

In any triangle $ABC$

If: $\frac{1}{8}\geq \cos A\cdot \cos B\cdot \cos C > y$, find  the value of $y$.

Comment: Abd what have you tried ?

Comment: @mathfighter I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609327/extreme-of-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-in-a-triangle-without-calculus  and  for the second part $$\cos A\ge ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the minimal value of
\begin{align} 
t&=\cos A\cdot \cos B\cdot \cos C 
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

where $A,B,C$ are the angles of $\triangle ABC$.

For any $\triangle ABC$ with
semiperimeter $\rho$
inradius $r$
and circumradius $R$,
we can
using a known expression
for
\eqref{1}
in terms of two parameters
$v=r/R$,
$v\in[0,\tfrac12]$,
and
$u=\rho/R=u(v)$,
for any valid value of $v$
$u(v)\in[u_{\min}(v),\, u_{\max}(v)]$:

\begin{align} 
t&=
\cos A\cdot \cos B\cdot \cos C 
=
\tfrac14\,(u(v)^2-(v+2)^2)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Expressions for the boundary values of $u$ are known to be

\begin{align}
u_{\min}(v)&=
\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2-2\sqrt{(1-2v)^3}}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
u_{\max}(v)&=
\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2+2\sqrt{(1-2v)^3}}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align} 
\min_{\triangle ABC}
&(\cos A\cdot \cos B\cdot \cos C)
=
\tfrac14\,\min_{v\in[0,1/2]}
(u_{\min}(v)^2-(v+2)^2)
\tag{5}\label{5}
\\
&=
\tfrac12
\,\min_{v\in[0,1/2]}
(v-(1-v)^2-\sqrt{(1-2v)^3})
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

It can be shown that the function in \eqref{6}
is increasing on $v\in[0,\tfrac12]$,
hence

\begin{align} 
\tfrac12
\,\min_{v\in[0,1/2]}
&(-(1-v)^2+v-\sqrt((1-2v)^3))
\tag{7}\label{7}
\\
&=
\tfrac12\,
(v-(1-v)^2-\sqrt{(1-2v)^3})|_{v=0}
=\tfrac12\cdot(-2)
=-1
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

It follows that
the minimal value of $t$  in \eqref{1} is $-1$,
which is reached only
for degenerate triangles
with two zero angles
and the third one of $180^\circ$.
Indeed,
\begin{align} 
\cos0^\circ\cdot\cos0^\circ\cdot\cos180^\circ
&=1\cdot1\cdot(-1)=-1
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}