# Prove $ (\frac{1}{cosA}-1)(\frac{1}{cosB}-1)(\frac{1}{cosC}-1) \ge 1$

Tags: inequality

*Let* $\triangle ABC$ *be a acute triangle. Prove that:* $$(\frac{1}{cosA}-1)(\frac{1}{cosB}-1)(\frac{1}{cosC}-1) \ge 1 $$
*My attempt:*
$$\Leftrightarrow (1-cosA)(1-cosB)(1-cosC)\ge cosA.cosB.cosC$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 1-2cosA.cosB.cosC + cosA.cosB + cosB.cosC+cosA.cosC \ge cosA+cosB+cosC $$
$$\Leftrightarrow cos^2A+cos^2B+cos^2C + cosA.cosB + cosB.cosC+cosA.cosC \ge cosA+cosB+cosC $$
$$ 0<cos A,cos B,cosC<1$$
$$cos^2A+cos^2B+cos^2C=1-2cosA.cosB.cosC\ge 3\sqrt[3]{cosA.cosB.cosC}$$
$$\Rightarrow cosA.cosB.cosC \le \frac{1}{8}$$
And I was stuck here. Could you help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extreme of $\cos A\cos B\cos C$ in a triangle without calculus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609327/extreme-of-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-in-a-triangle-without-calculus) Found using Approach0.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Use AM-GM and Jensen's inequalities: $\cos A\cos B\cos C \le \dfrac{(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^3}{27}\le \dfrac{1}{27}\cdot (3\cos (\frac{A+B+C}{3}))^3=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 =\dfrac{1}{8}.$

Comment: Better would be to jensen $f(x)=\log (\cos x)$ gives result instantly!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Oh yeah.Just missed it !

Comment: @The73SuperBug oh no, i proved it in my solution

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$1- \cos A = 1-  \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} = \frac{(a+b-c)(c+a-b)}{2bc},$$
so
$$(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C) = \frac{(a+b-c)^2(b+c-a)^2(c+a-b)^2}{8a^2b^2c^2},$$
and
$$\cos A \cos B \cos C = \frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2)}{8a^2b^2c^2}.$$
Thefore, the original inequality become
$$(a+b-c)^2(b+c-a)^2(c+a-b)^2 \geqslant (a^2+b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2).$$
It's remain to prove that
$$(a+b-c)^2(c+a-b)^2 \geqslant (a^2+b^2-c^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2).$$
But, this is true because
$$(a+b-c)^2(c+a-b)^2 - (a^2+b^2-c^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2) = 2(b-c)^2(b^2+c^2-a^2) \geqslant 0.$$
The proof is completed.

Comment: em cảm ơn Anh cho em xin fb em học hỏi được không ạ ^^

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore a beautiful solution !

Comment: có tư tưởng nào để giải quyết chỗ cuối không anh. Làm sao để anh nhận ra $(a+b-c)^2(c+a-b)^2 \geqslant (a^2+b^2-c^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2)$ thế ạ, vì có những TH khai triển ra khá trâu mà khi ghép lại ko ra nhân tử chung hoặc phải chứng minh tiếp 1 bất đẳng thức khác cũng trâu thì sao ạ

Comment: Nó là kỹ thuật “ghép đối xứng”, em tìm đọc trong quyển [AM-GM](https://shopee.vn/S%C3%A1ch--S%E1%BB%AD-D%E1%BB%A5ng-Ph%C6%B0%C6%A1ng-Ph%C3%A1p-Am--Gm-%C4%90%E1%BB%83-Ch%E1%BB%A9ng-Minh-B%E1%BA%A5t-%C4%90%E1%BA%B3ng-Th%E1%BB%A9c-i.135852798.6144365833) của anh Cẩn và Quốc Anh.